# Define variables as variables in Robot Framework with Python file

Tags: python, selenium, variables, robotframework, python-appium

This works

```
<<file1.robot>>

**Setting**
Resource               file2.robot

**Variables**
${file1_var1}          ${file2_var1}

**Keyword**
Check It
    Click               ${file1_var1}
```

where

```
<<file2.robot>>

**Settings**
Variables               file2Locator.py
```

```
<<file2Locator.py>>
file2_var1 = "id=Clickable"
```

Click   id=Clickable    is called successfully, with keyword "Click It"

However, the following FAILS:

```
<<file1Fail.robot>>

**Setting**
Resource               file2.robot
Variables              file1Fail.py     firstSet

**Keyword**
Check It
    Click               ${file1_var1}
```

Where

```
<<file1Fail.py>>

SetOneVar = {'file1_var1': "${file2_var1}"}

def get_variables(arg):
    if arg == 'firstSet': return SetOneVar
    else return
```

due to the error where UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=${file2_var1}] clearly does not work.
In other words, upon getting variables from a python file 1, Click ${file2_var1} is literally called, instead of Click id=Clickable. "${file2_var1}" is not being replaced by "id=Clickable" anymore.

Any solution to this? How to call define a variable as another variable imported at another resource file

Comment: By looking at the sample, file1Fail.py defines one variable (only) - `SetOneVar`, so I'm surprised it doesn't even fail that file1_var1is undefined when you tried using it. Another thing is - why would you expect the `"${file2_var1}"` inside the dict to be replaced by any other value? That's defined in the python code, and for it it's just a string (that for you looks like a RF var, but for py - it's just a string). What/when should substitute it with anything else?

Comment: I am not sure by what you mean by "file1_var1is undefined". It is defined in the Python dictionary. Perhaps you can find out more here:https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#getting-variables-from-a-special-function

Comment: I believe my intention is rather clear; I hope to define a variable, as a variable (which is imported into, at another robot file), by importing the relevant robot file.

Comment: I stand corrected, you do export `file1_var1` as the variable from the .py file. The other part from my comment still holds though - its value is the string `${file2_var1}`, the framework did not substitute it.

Comment: Yes hoping to find out how we can substitute it?

Answer (score 0):

In the python file the value of the variable you've defined (`file1_var1`) is set to the string `${file2_var1}` (which looks like a RF variable definition due to the `$` and `{}`, but it's just a string). When the framework imports it as a variable file, it does not automatically substitute it - "you set the value to be a string, you're getting a string".

Later on, after it's imported you can substitute/replace it with the value behind `${file2_var1}` - as long as that `file2_var1` is defined in the current scope. That's done by calling [Replace Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Replace%20Variables) which returns the substituted version (e.g. doesn't modify the original variable):

```
${file2_var1}=    Replace Variables    ${file2_var1}
```